libvlc 3.x: how to player video (with audio) using callback apis?
How to implement video (with audio) playbacks using callback apis with libvlc 3.0?
(libvlc_video_set_callbacks / libvlc_audio_set_callbacks)

3.x branch of vlc repo does not contain any example on using callback apis.
There is an example for video on vlc wiki, but:

It does not includes audio handling;
It does not work on my distribution libvlc-3.0.16:
avi demux error: no key frame set for track 1  (where track 1 is audio)
(vlc program can handle the same media files without problem)


I also tried to build libvlc-4.0, but it is crashy.


One question to a question -- ideally we'd have one about the VLC 4.x crashes, and a second one about the 3.x wiki example not working as advertised, each with relevant technical details (such as a stack trace) and a [MRE] included inside the text of the question itself.

@CharlesDuffy Those two are not what I want to ask. They are included to show what I have investigated, the example is only half of what I asked (even if it is working) and libvlc-4.0 are no more than a workaround (if it worked).

Those were suggested as examples of alternate questions that are specific and concrete enough to be on topic here. There's too much left up in the air here -- we don't know your OS compatibility requirements, so we don't know which audio layers are acceptable. We don't know if SDL is the only acceptable video layer or just an example of one; etc, etc. Part of the point of insisting that you include specific code in the question itself is so those decisions are already made instead of being things we need to interrogate you over.

@CharlesDuffy Unmentioned = no-constraint. If you really understand the solution, you can make answers or suggestions that don't depend on specific window system/graphics api/audio output. Please stop nitpicking and derailing the question.

I have no interest in making an attempt until there's a sufficiently well-defined problem. (Last time I built video playback tooling was in the mid-2000s -- it's a place where I have domain experience, but it's old domain experience, so there'd be actual work needed to refresh myself; not going to do that until it's obvious that the problem is well-defined enough to be tractable -- and moreover, the site rules require that problems be narrow and specific, so nitpicking until we have a problem specific enough to have a [mre], and voting to close otherwise, is in line with rule enforcement).
